# Double quotes and trailing equal sign missing from cookies values in ServletExec

Tags: servlets, cookies

I have a servlet app which stores cookies as base64-encoded strings. On a server where the app is running on ServletExec, the cookies' values are not wrapped in quotes. Additionally, if the value ends with a '=' character, that character is removed. The missing quotes and trailing '=' prevent the cookies' values from being parsed properly. In 2 other servers where this app is running on ServletExec and Tomcat where this app is working, the cookies are wrapped in double quotes and the trailing '=' sign is not removed.

As seen in a browser's developer tool:

Bad - cookiename:dGVzdHN0cmluZzE

Expected - cookiename:"dGVzdHN0cmluZzE="

Any idea what's stripping out the quotes and the trailing '=' sign? TIA!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the servlet `Cookie` class follows the [Version 0 cookie spec](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html). Here's a cite from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html):

> This class supports both the Version 0 (by Netscape) and Version 1 (by RFC 2109) cookie specifications. By default, cookies are created using Version 0 to ensure the best interoperability.

Version 0 cookie values are restrictive in allowed characters. It only allows URL-safe characters. This covers among others the alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) and only a few lexical characters, including `-`, `_`, `.`, `~` and `%`. All other characters are invalid in version 0 cookies, including `"` and `=`. If the server doesn't already do it, the browser will swallow the invalid characters.

Your best bet is to URL-encode those characters. This way every character which is not allowed in URLs will be percent-encoded in this form `%xx` which is valid as cookie value.

So, when creating the cookie do:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
// ...
```

And when reading the cookie, do:

```
String value = URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8");
// ...
```

An alternative is to switch to Version 1 cookies via `Cookie#setVersion()`, but this isn't supported in IE<=11.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know whether setting the cookie spec version can be done via a configuration in Servletexec or Tomcat? I'm just confused by the fact that the same app is behaving differently in two servers running ServletExec.

Comment: Some servers (Tomcat, JBoss, etc) implicitly change to version 1 when you set wrong characters as cookie vaule. This is consequence of a fix to a security bug. However that would fail for IE users (it doesn't obey the maxage and the cookie will behave as a session cookie).